# Using shared variables in pthread

Tags: c++, pthreads, mutex

In the example code below, I'm using shared variables to pass information to the threads. The maintest will be called few times and each time, it will create a new thread with new information. I use mutex locking to make sure the shared data is correctly passing to the corresponding thread.

For some reason, i could not use struct data type to pass the information as arguments to the thread due to the software i'm using has custom data type and every time it will crash my application.

Can someone please advise if my implementation below is correct?

```
    void* fun1(void* a);    

    int threadCnt;
    int        arg_tnum;
    float    arg_measArray;
    string     arg_waveID;
    float      arg_Freq;
    bool       arg_enablePlots;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex1 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
    pthread_t th1[10];

    void maintest()
    {     
        pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex1 );
        arg_tnum =  threadcnt+10;
        arg_freq = arg_tnum * 2;
        arg_measArray = arg_Freq *3;
        arg_enablePlots =true;
        pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex1 );

       threadCnt = threadCnt+1;
       pthread_create(&th1[threadCnt],NULL,fun1,NULL);

    } 

    void* fun1(void* a)
    {
      int index;
      float freq;
      float meas;
      bool  enableplt;

      pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex1 );
      index = arg_tnum;
      freq = arg_Freq;
      meas = arg_measArray;
      enableplt = arg_enablePlots;
      pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex1 );

      //print all the values
      cout << index << endl;
      cout << freq << endl;
      cout << meas << endl;
      cout << enableplt << endl;
      return NULL;
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Why not use standard mechanism, i.e. `std::thread` and `std::mutex`?

2) No, code is not correct. There is no any guarantees that `fun1()` will be executed, and read its arguments, before second call to `maintest()` will overwrite shared data.

Comment: 2) Isn't the mutex lock will ensure the shared data be locked when the maintest() is updating the values? Also the maintest() is non threaded and it's running in series.

Comment: You current code will ensure that data will not be read while modified and that data will not be modified while it is read (which basically is same, from different points of view). But there is no any mechanisms that prevent overwriting data second time before its read. Regarding `maintest()` being non-threaded you are worng. `maintest()` also executing in some thread, lets name it "main", and nothing, except inter-thread synchronization, can guarantee that it wont be called twice before `fun1()` will read shared values.

Comment: Aha....i got what you meant....May i know what will be fix for the inter-thread synchronization? Some sample code is much appreciated.

Comment: For example you can use conditional variable in conjunction with some flag. So it should work something like that: In `maintest()` check that flag is not set, before writing arguments, wait on conditional variable if it is set. When writing arguments set this flag. In `func1()` reset this flag and notify conditional variable after reading arguments.